# Thermodynamics of zinc chloride to zinc

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, chemical-compounds

I am trying to deposit zinc metal from zinc chloride using chemical vapor deposition. But it is thermodynamically feasible to obtain zinc from zinc chloride?

Comment: what is the entalphy of formation of ZnCl2 at your conditions? Do you even know that?

Comment: No, at the current stage I am investigating what temperature will the reaction become possible

Comment: Well, your question is useless if we know at what condition!

Comment: This might be a better fit for Chemistry stack exchange

Comment: @MahderT: The question basically is whether there's any condition for which the enthalpy of formation is negative. There's no a priori condition.

Answer (score 1):

From http://chemicals.etacude.com/z/zinc_chloride.php it would seem that the enthalpy of formation of zinc chloride is -415 kJ/mol.  It has a melting point of 290C and a boiling point of 732C.  Since it seems happy to boil (and make a smoke screen), you would need to go above (given the formation energy well above) 732C to get it to dissociate by itself on a non-catalyzed surface. The feasibility of this is left to your circumstances.

My copy of The Chemistry of Metal CVD (Kodas and Hampden-Smith) indicates that CVD of pure Zn had not been well studied (but the book is 20 years old now).  Instead, they suggest di-methyl- or di-ethyl-zinc have been used as precursors, though mainly for ZnS, or as a dopant in III-V materials.